# Recommended way to populate foreign key?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a table story and comment where comment has a foreign key to story and im using a modelform with comment as the model where the field comment_text will get the data typed in by the user, but i also need to populate the foreign key in the comment table (storyID) with the value of the story it is associated with. I have the story ID as a parameter to the view function but i cant see any ways to add this value to the form after it has been submitted, what is the recommended way of doing this ?

Edit: Updated with view and form.

This is the view:

```
def add_comment(request, specific_story):
     """ Process a new comment """
     story_details = Story.objects.get(id=specific_story)

     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = NewComment(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return render(request, "base/story/display_story.html", {'story_details': story_details, 'form': form})
         else:
             form = NewComment()
             return render(request, "base/story/display_story.html", {'story_details': story_details, 'form': form})
     else:
         return render(request, "base/story/display_story.html", {'story_details': story_details })
```

Form:

```
class NewComment(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Comment
         fields = ['comment_text']
         widgets = {
             'comment_text': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
         }
```

Comment: please post your view, and form code

Comment: original post updated with view and form code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.save(commit=False)
    comment.story = story_details
    comment.save()
    return ...
```

Comment: thanks, thought about commit=False but didnt think of that the save method returned the object :)